# Is there any In-Memory Distributed Hash Table implementation Perl?

Tags: perl, in-memory, dht

I am looking for an in memory distributed hash table implementation in Perl.
Does any one have any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an implementation that you can use from Perl, there are a number of modules for interfacing to Memcached e.g.: [Cache::Memcached::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cache::Memcached::Fast).

If you're looking for an implementation that is written in Perl then I don't have a suggestion.